# How npm checks that a package version is become vulnerable and show it in command prompt?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am working on a react project and I am using various npm packages. Now there were 1002 vulnerable packages when I started fixing/updating my old packages. And at last this only 20 vulnerable packages were remained which were also very low priority.

But now again after 3 months the vulnerability has increase to 925 vulnerable packages. So my question is, when I am using packages.lock.json for installing a specific package version only. Then how the vulnerabilities increased. I mean is there any mechanism which npm follow before telling "this package is vulnerable." I want to know how npm check if this package is vulnerable or not. Even when it was fine before and I am using same package version with same node version as well.

Comment: People find and report vulnerabilities in existing released software. If you do nothing, unless everything you're using is already perfect, you'll see more and more of those packages become known-vulnerable (they were vulnerable before, you just didn't necessarily know it).

Comment: But I want to know how it shows in our command prompt that this package is vulnerable. How npm does that? I mean is there any backend api call or something else is there that shows this? 

Also when I run npm audit it shows vulnerable packages. So how does it happen?

Comment: Yes, there'll be an API call. If you want to know what npm audit does, read the docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit#description

Comment: Thanks for this. Still no need to down vote my question. But thanks for help

Comment: Votes on comments don't get you any rep, why would I care about that? Did you read the docs I just shared? What do you imagine *"submits a description"* to look like if *not* an API call? Note if you use the `--verbose` flag you can *see* the API call: `npm http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits`

Comment: One more thing what is this default registry means. Can you explain that too?

Comment: It's the registry that is your default; again, see the docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/registry.

Answer (score 0):

`npm` as a package manager runs **audit** of the installed/installing dependencies to check for the vulnerabilities posted/reported on that particular NPM package you installed/installing. It list them out to notify/warn you about the problem you might encounter, using such packages.

It will be an API call from npm to the registry. Read further: [docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit#description](http://npm%20Audit)

One can manually audit its dependencies as well. using the following command:

```
npm audit
```

Make sure you are running this command in the same directory where your `package-lock.json` exists.

If you are using `yarn` as a package manager, you can run:

```
yarn audit
```

Answer (score -3):

Here is a great explanation on npm vulnerability.

https://snyk.io/blog/understanding-filesystem-takeover-vulnerabilities-in-npm-javascript-package-manager/

NPM vulnerability check mainly depends on the version and last publish date of each packages.